# SSL Certificate creation - Which ID type to choose?

Tags: vpn, ssl-certificate, certificate

I'm trying to find-out how important the "ID type" for a SSL certificate is.  I'm trying to generate a cert from my firewall to upload to a CA, but having trouble deciding if I should choose an IP, a domain name, or email for the ID Type (subject information).

Any insight to choosing which one would help (particularly if there is a best practice for VPN SSL certificates).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most likely you'll want to use a Domain Name as the subject - but it depends what exactly you're wanting to encrypt using this certificate.

The most common case is access to an SSL port from the internet, for something like SSL-based VPN or an encypting reverse proxy; for that, you'll want the use a Domain Name subject type, and for the data in the subject field you'll want to use the DNS name that clients will be using to access the server - for the VPN use case, that might be something like `vpn.example.com`.

Let us know what the certificate's going to be for, and we can be more specific.

Comment: Yes, this is for an SSL port on our firewall (SSL-based VPN).  Sounds like if an "A" record for the firewall's public IP is forwarded to mainvpn.exmple.com is added in DNS, then my certificate's subject should really be it?

Comment: @mrtechalot Yes, that's correct.

Comment: Thank you.  If you upvote me, I can have upvote rights and give you some extra points.  update: scratch that, already have enough to upvote.